# Avoid using synchronized lock on an object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have my below method in a `SocketManager` class which is called by background thread every 60 seconds. It will ping a socket and check whether it is live or not and put everything in a `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map.

```
  private final Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
      new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  // runs every 60 seconds to ping all the socket to make sure whether they are alive or not
  private void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, List<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, List<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketHolder> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketHolder liveSocket : liveSockets) {
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();
        Message message = new Message(holder, Partition.COMMAND);

        // pinging to see whether a socket is live or not
        boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(message.getAdd(), holder, socket);
        boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;

        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveUpdatedSockets.add(zmq);
      }
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets));
    }
  }
```

Also I have below methods in the same `SocketManager` class.  `getNextSocket()` method will be called by multiple reader threads (let's say 10 threads max) concurrently to get the next live socket.

```
  // this method will be called by multiple threads concurrently to get the next live socket
  public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    for (Datacenters dc : Datacenters.getOrderedDatacenters()) {
      Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc));
      if (liveSocket.isPresent()) {
        return liveSocket;
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocket(final List<SocketHolder> listOfEndPoints) {
    if (!listOfEndPoints.isEmpty()) {
      // The list of live sockets
      List<SocketHolder> liveOnly = new ArrayList<>(listOfEndPoints.size());
      for (SocketHolder obj : listOfEndPoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          liveOnly.add(obj);
        }
      }
      if (!liveOnly.isEmpty()) {
        // The list is not empty so we shuffle it an return the first element
        return Optional.of(liveOnly.get(random.nextInt(liveOnly.size()))); // just pick one
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to make sure all those 10 threads + timer thread should never use same socket after calling `getNextSocket()` method.

- If timer thread is working on `socketA` in `updateLiveSockets()` method, then all those 10 thread should work on other live sockets (each of those 10 working on different live socket)
- And all those 10 thread should always work on different live socket.
- Also if we have more reader threads than we have live sockets available then I still need to make sure each reader threads work on different live socket. As soon as one reader thread is done with a live socket then other reader thread can use that socket immediately or any better approach. I want to minimize the blocking time as much as I can do.

What is the best way to solve this problem? I can have `synchronize` on a socket from those 10 reader threads plus in timer thread as well which will guarantee that only thread is working on that socket but I don't want to use synchronization here. There must be a better way to ensure that every thread uses a different single live socket at the same time instead of synchronization on a particular socket. I have around 60 socket and around 10 reader threads plus 1 timer threads. Do I need to use `ThreadLocal` concept here?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for your problem is to use [ConcurrentQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)
You don't need to use ThreadLocal. ConcurrentQueue is non-blocking and very efficient for multi-threading environment.
For example this is how would you remove sockets that are not alive and keep the ones that are alive.

```
    private final Map<Datacenters, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
          new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


// runs every 60 seconds to ping 70 sockets the socket to make sure whether they are alive or not (it does not matter if you ping more sockets than there are in the list because you are rotating the que)
  private void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, List<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, List<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
    Queue<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      for (int i = 0; i<70; i++) {
            SocketHolder s = liveSockets.poll();
        Socket socket = s.getSocket();
        String endpoint = s.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();
        Message message = new Message(holder, Partition.COMMAND);

        // pinging to see whether a socket is live or not
        boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(message.getAdd(), holder, socket);
        boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;

        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, s.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveSockets.add(zmq);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am still not following your solution? How does this make sure that timer thread and reader threads are not working on same socket?

Comment: if you use SocketHolder s = liveSockets.poll() in both timer and the threads then no one can get the same socket. Of course make sure that you return the socket in the pool when you are done with it.

Comment: I see now.. It started to make sense now.. Few questions I have. First is how my `getLiveSocket` method will look like which is called by multiple reader threads concurrently to get the next live socket available? I am confuse on that.. And secondly how does my reader thread will return the socket once they are done using it? can you provide an example on these two things?

Comment: you can change getLiveSocket to accept ConcurrentLinkedQueue<SocketHolder> instead of List and then you would poll from that queue. In the thread when you are done with the socket you add it back to the queue. Queue is concurrent so no two threads will have the same socket.

Comment: hmm I see. Do you think you can add an example on how `getLiveSocket` will work and also how will I put the socket back in queue? Little bit confuse on that. Also looks like with this solution, in my updated `updateLiveSockets` method, I won't be iterating all the sockets because all the reader threads will be removing live sockets from the queue so there is some race condition because of which I won't be iterating all the sockets. Right?

Comment: so my point is- if pinger thread is pinging a socket to check whether they are live or not then no other business thread should use that socket. Similarly if business thread is using a socket to send data on it, then pinger thread should not ping that socket. And this applies to all the socket. But I need to make sure that in `updateLiveSockets` method, we are pinging all the available sockets whenever my background thread starts so that we can figure out which socket is live or dead.

Comment: Right now problem is, If I am synchronizing on a `socket` which will block all the business thread to send data on it if multiple business threads picks same socket and I am trying to avoid that but at the same time, need to make sure that my pinger thread is pinging all the available sockets to check whether they are live or dead.

Comment: Pinger thread will go through all sockets in ConcurrentLinkedQueue and these are the sockets that are not used by other threads. When a thread wants to use a socket it polls that socket from that queue so pinger thread cannot ping that socket.

Comment: Do you think you can update your answer with this logic to help me understand better. As of now little confuse still on how this will work. I think there will be a race condition still where pinger thread might not be able to ping all the available sockets.

Comment: yes, unfortunately cannot do it now but will update later on.

Answer (score 0):

Just from you first requirement: "I want to make sure all those 10 threads + timer thread should never use same socket after calling getNextSocket() method.". **My answer is that you can't do this without a ThreadLocal.**

As for maximising the usage of those sockets, you definitely need some sort of socket pool to manage them, so that you can request and release them. Every time you request a socket, you "mark it" as used by the current thread, that's here the ThreadLocal comes in where you move the socket reference into the ThreadLocal, so that the next call to the getNextSocket() just goes in there and checks if exists and returns, if not go to the socket poll and pull a new one and set it on the ThreadLocal.
You will always need to release the socket back into the pool, don't forget that. Maybe create some sort of abstraction to the socket itself so that you can use the AutoCloseable interface to make the release to the socket pool, much more easy.

Comment: Do you can provide an example basis on my code to demonstrate this? This will help me better to understand this. As of now I am confuse on this will work?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to implement some type of Socket pool and have the Threads, once they are done, to release the socket back to the pool. The synchronization would only happen only at retrieval and release of the socket from/to the pool. Once the socket is retrieved all the access to it can be done without synchronization. IMHO, I dont see how ThreadLocal's can help you here.

Here is code showing the approach:

```
  public synchrnozed Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    for (Datacenters dc : Datacenters.getOrderedDatacenters()) {
      Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc));
      if ( liveSocket.isPresent() && !liveSocket.isUsed() ) {
        liveSocket.setUsed(true);
        return liveSocket;
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  public synchrnozed release(SocketHolder s){
     s.setUsed(false);
  }
```

and each thread will look like this:

```
  new Thread( new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
       SocketHolder sh = null;
       try{
           sh = socketManager.getNextSocket();
           //do some work on socker
       }finally{
           if (sh != null) socketManager.release(sh);
       }
     }
  }; ) ).start();
```

Comment: yeah interesting idea. Can you provide an example on how this socket pool will work here?

Comment: since `getNextSocket()` can be called by multiple threads so this line `        liveSocket.setUsed(true);` will be thread safe? Also if lets say we have less number of live sockets available than we have threads, then this approach can send `Optional.absent();` sometime right?

Comment: `getNextSocket` is now synchronized in my sample code. If all sockets are used then, yes, you wont get a socket. You can optionally add logic to create additional sockets (up to a set threshold) or just have the calling thread wait (up to a set timeout) for a socket to released.

Comment: Can I use `BlockingQueue` here to make this work instead of adding another method `setUsed` and synchronizing `getNextSocket` method?